# HTTP could not register URL (remote debugging)

Tags: wcf, remote-debugging

C#, Windows 7.
I write an AutoCAD plugin and use the remote debuging (MS Visual Studio). My plugin must work as a WCF service. AutoCAD is unmanaged application and must to be as a host for my service. I am reading a book about WCF, and I try use it. I can't use acad.exe.config for my service settings: I have not permission. So I do it myself (I will read them from my xml file, but later, after refactoring). Code of my "server" (this code start by AutoCAD):

```
private static void RunServices() {
  Ap.Document doc = cad.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
  try {
    Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/CadService");
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.Name = "httpBinding";
    binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
    host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CadService));
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICadService), binding, address);
    host.Open(); // I get an Exception here...
    if (doc != null) {
      doc.Editor.WriteMessage("Service launched.\n");
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    if (doc != null) {
      doc.Editor.WriteMessage("Exception: {0}\n", ex.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

I get an exception (look the code comment):

```
Exception: HTTP could not register URL http://+:8000/CadServices/. 
Your process does not have access rights to this namespace 
(see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).
```

But the `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353` page is not exist. I try launch MS Visual Studio 2013 as admin (I read about this [here](http://devdex.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/solution-for-an-exception-in-wcf-http-could-not-register-url-http8000essentialwcf-your-process-does-not-have-access-rights-to-this-namespace/)), but It is not help me (look P.S.2 bellow).

P.S. If I launch AutoCAD as admin - all works fine.
P.S.2 If I launch the *remote debugger* as admin - all works fine too.
But I need use it as a usual user. Can I start my service (hosted in the AutoCAD) without the admin rights?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because AutoCad does not have the required rights to register the port in HTTP.SYS.  In that case you have two options:

1. Start Autocad in Admin mode
2. Register the port / endpoint in HTTP.SYS manually.  For this, there are several tools available.  This is the one I would use : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager

Let me know if this works